# ¿Cómo realizar paginación adecuadamente?

Tags: php, mysql

El siguiente código que mostraré a continuación imprime los datos de la tabla "posts" de manera descendente.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($config_db,$query);
if ($result) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $user = $row['user'];
        echo '<p>'.$user.'</p>';
        echo '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo ocurre como quiero que ocurra, pero, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que el resultado se divida en (por ejemplo) 5 resultados por página y las páginas se creen automáticamente?

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```
// Número de resultados por página
$results_per_page = 5;

// Consulta para obtener el número total de filas
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM posts";
$result = $config_db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$total_results = $row['total'];

// Calcula el número total de páginas
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $results_per_page);

// Obtiene la página actual
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
$page = 1; // Página predeterminada es la primera
} else {
$page = $_GET['page'];
}

// Calcula el desplazamiento
$offset = ($page - 1) * $results_per_page;

// Consulta para obtener los valores de la tabla posts con la paginación aplicada
$sql = "SELECT user, title, description FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $results_per_page";
$result = $config_db->query($sql);

// Imprime los resultados
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<p>".$row["user"]."</p>";
echo "<p>".$row["title"]."</p>";
echo "<p>".$row["description"]."</p>";
echo "<hr>";
}
} else {
echo "No se encontraron resultados.";
}

// Imprime los enlaces de paginación
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
echo "<a href='foro.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Un detalla a considerar, deberías validar que `$_GET['page']` es un entero mayor a cero.